# "Jirafe credentials are not set" warning from Commerce

Tags: 7, commerce

After install Commerce Kickstart 2.7, there is a warning:

> Jirafe credentials are not set. Get your credentials at Jirafe

What is `Jirafe` and `Jirafe credentials`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jirafe](http://jirafe.com/) is an analytics, alerting, and automation platform that is deeply integrated into ecommerce, marketing, and other platforms.

The [Jirafe](http://drupal.org/project/jirafe) module integrates Jirafe with Drupal Commerce, and allows the following features:

> View your visits, orders, revenue, conversion %, AOV (average order value), and RPV (revenue per visit). This information can give you a great summary of your business at a glance. See how your visitors become customers at 5 critical points in your application. Easily see when visitors leave your site, so that you know what areas of your site to improve.

As you are using Commerce Kickstart, the module is already enabled. To configure You just need to:

- Click on the Reports tab of your administration menu, or access admin/commerce/jirafe
- Enter your credentials (Application ID and Token) that you get from jirafe and click Save

Answer (score 0):

[Jirafe](http://drupal.org/project/jirafe) is a web service providing customer analytics. You have to subscribe (free) to the service, hence the requirement for credentials.